# how to return view html into controller to ajax success

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to return whole html into controller to ajax response. I am using render() but not getting any data into the return method

Below is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '{{url('/filter_each_video')}}',
                            data : { resolution : myCheckboxes, fps : myCheckboxesfps },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                               
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                // console.log(data);
                            }
                });
```

Below is my controller from where actually render the view

```
function filter_each_video(){
        if(request()->ajax()){
            
            $item = Item::whereIn('format', $_GET['resolution'])->get();
            $formats = DB::table('items')->select('format')->distinct()->get();
            $fps = DB::table('items')->select('fps')->distinct()->get();
            $data['item_count'] = $item;
            $data['item'] = $item;
            $data= $this->sellWise($data);
            $data= $this->starWise($data);
            $data= $this->dateWise($data);
            return view('frontend.pages.videos_for_each_filter', compact('data','formats','fps'))->render();
        }
    }
```

Below is the view file from where I am set value and tha whole html return to controller to ajax response

```
<?php
        $html ="";
               $html.= '<div class="row video-list">';

               foreach($data['item'] as $video){

                  $html.= '<div class="item video-item сol-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 text-white mb-4 pull-left">
                        <div class="item-wrapper display-7">
                            <div class="item-img">Video Name</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>';

                }

                $html.= '</div>';

    return $html;

?>
```

If anyone have idea what exact i am doing wrong to fetch html content to controller then please let me know

I want to return whole html to the ajax response

Comment: Can you please change `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'html', ` inside the ajax?

Comment: @ Shamir Imtiaz still not getting any response.

Comment: Do you get properly the data from controller? Please just pass in random data like `return "hello";` in controller and check the data is properly coming in ajax `success:`.

Comment: @Shamir Imtiaz from controller return data commingin ajax success. Return Hello pproperly comes in ajax success:

Comment: Sir, inside your view, you dont need to return html or anything. Just use normal php/blade code in view file. Please update your code and let me know the code is working.

Comment: @Shamir Imtiaz I removed html But still I am getting empty data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238210/discussion-between-shamir-imtiaz-and-praful).

Answer (score 0):

(1) Have you tried with `response($output, 200, $headers)`?

```
$html = view('frontend.pages.videos_for_each_filter', compact('data','formats','fps'))
           ->render();

\Log::debug('Rendered HTML', ['html'=>$html]);

return response($html,200);
```

Check your `/storage/logs` to double check the `$html` is right.

(2) You can also try with JSON:

```
return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
```

And on client side,

```
console.log("res is ", response.data.html);
```

On a side note, you should validate the request data and not use `$_GET` directly. Your controller method should look more like this...

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // (? From memory, maybe check the namespace)

public function filter_each_video(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['resolution' => 'required|string']);

    if( $request->ajax() ){

        $item = Item::whereIn('format', $request->resolution)->first();

        // ... cont'd
    }
}
```

If you're getting an empty response, throw some `\Log::debug` statements in there and find out where you're losing the response.

Comment: I tried both above but in response I am getting empty data. Like this {"html":""}

Comment: Did you check your storage logs to make sure that `$html` is not empty?